# What will happen if we point an integer pointer to the beginning of a character array and dereference it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[]="ABCD EFGH";
    int *x=&s[0];
    printf("%d %d\n", *x, x);
    x=s;
    printf("%d %d\n", *x, x);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", &s[0], s, &s);
}
```

Can I get to know about the explanation of the output of this code?

Comment: Well, using anything but the `%p` format and a corresponding `void *` argument to print a pointer is undefined...

Comment: @Jarod42: No implicit conversion?

Comment: @skrrrt Yup, it is.

Comment: @Jarod42 it will compile

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland: Was tagged C++... and languages differ :)

Comment: As you're already deep into UB land, maybe try `printf("%x" ...)` to see hexadecimal instead of decimal (`'A'` ==> `0x41`)

Comment: @Jarod42 I see `C` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because using `*x` after `int *x=&s[0];` violates a rule in the C standard. C 2018 6.5 7 says:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

`*x` attempts to access the bytes of `s` as if they were an `int` object. However, the effective type of this memory is `char` (C 2018 6.5 6: “The *effective type* of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any…”). So:

- `int` is not compatible with the effective type, `char`.
- `int` is not a qualified version of a type compatible with `char`.
- `int` is not a signed or unsigned type corresponding to `char`.
- `int` is not a signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of `char`.
- `int` is not an aggregate or union type of any sort.
- `int` is not a character type.

Violating this requirement means the behavior is not defined, per C 2018 4 2:

> If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined…

Since the behavior is undefined by the C standard, compilers may choose to define what they will do with it or not to define what they will do with it. In the latter case, optimization by the compiler can cause the program to produce surprising results. In the former case, a common behavior by compilers is to evaluate `*x` by reinterpreting the bytes it points to as an `int` type, provided the address is suitably aligned for an `int` object. (GCC and Clang allow this with the command-line switch `-fno-strict-aliasing`.)

That is, if `&s[0]` is an address where an `int` is allowed to start in the C implementation, then `*x` will produce an `int` value taken from the bytes starting at `&s[0]`. If the C implementation is using ASCII, the first four bytes of `s` are 41<sub>16</sub>, 42<sub>16</sub>, 43<sub>16</sub>, and 44<sub>16</sub>. Then, if the `int` is four eight-bit bytes stored little-endian (with less significant bytes at lower addresses), and `s` is acceptably aligned for an `int`, then the value of `*x` will be 44434241<sub>16</sub>, which is 1,145,258,561 in decimal.

In summary, getting this result requires a lot of implementation-dependent behavior:

- `s` is suitably aligned for an `int` object.
- The C implementation supports aliasing `char` objects using `int`.
- The C implementation uses ASCII and eight-bit bytes.
- `int` is four bytes in the C implementation.
- The C implementation stores `int` objects in little endian order.